# can not connect my device to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, usb-debugging

I am trying to connect my device(galaxy s3 jellybean rom) to my computer so that I can test the app I have written on my phone.
the problem is that when I connect my device to the pc in usb-debugging,eclipse tries to connect to my phone,but it can't.In the logCat I can see this error appearing so many times:

"openning of usb file failed fd is -1 & errno is 13"

I think it is good to mention that I connected my phone to my computer successfully before.But suddenly,today it won't connect.any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Restart your phone , i don't know why this case happiness in galaxy S3 with me ,but not other devices each time i have to restart the device so the computer will detect it .

Answer (score 1):

I keep getting

`11-13 09:35:51.999: E/DataRouter(95): Opening of the USB File failed fd is -1 & errno is 2`

as well, however this doesnt stop me from attaching my device to my computer.
One of these may work for you

- Restart your phone
- Restart eclipse
- Update eclipse to the latest version
- Download the latest APIs (currently API 19)
- Download latest drivers (this may be needed if you have upgraded your phone/device software recently)